# Why is the subcall gas limit set to 63/64th of the remaining gas?

Tags: security, call-depth-attacks, stack

From the solidity docs:

> Calls are limited to a depth of 1024, which means that for more complex operations, loops should be preferred over recursive calls. Furthermore, only 63/64th of the gas can be forwarded in a message call, which causes a depth limit of a little less than 1000 in practice.

I know there are some [security considerations](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.11/security-considerations.html#callstack-depth) for setting a limit on how much a callee can consume, but I'm curious to know why did they set the value to 63/64, specifically? Was it just efficient to divide by 64 and subtract the result?

Answer (score 4):

There is link describing how `63/64` rule allowed to execute transaction but to waste a lot of gas instead of just failing: https://github.com/Synthetixio/synthetix/issues/243